# before the start of resultset

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Here I am trying to get name, mat, eng, sci mark based on idno1 but I couldn't get the desired output. If I use while(rs.next()){} method, it is pointing to the last row in SQL. So can someone help me, please.I have attached my code below

```
public class display extends javax.swing.JFrame 
{
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/person?useSSL=false";
String name = "Vzlys";
String Pass = "Vzlys@1995";
String query = "select * from details where idno=?";
String query1 = "select * from details";
String id1,name1,mat1,eng1,sci1;
Connection con = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement st = null;
private void closeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    this.dispose();
}                                     
 private void submitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,name,Pass);
        st  = con.prepareStatement(query);
        id1 = iddis.getText();
        rs = st.executeQuery(query1);
            while(rs.next())
            {
                if(id1 == rs.getString(1))
                {
                    data = 1;
                }
            }
            if(data==1)
            {
                name1 = rs.getString(2);
                mat1 = rs.getString(3);
                eng1 = rs.getString(4);
                sci1 = rs.getString(5);
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid idno");//IT IS ONLY PRINTING THIS
            }
            namedis.setText(name1);
            matdis.setText(mat1);
            engdis.setText(eng1);
            scidis.setText(sci1);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }
}
```

Comment: while(rs.next()) { if(id1 == rs.getString(1)) { data = 1; } } if(data==1) { name1 = rs.getString(2); mat1 = rs.getString(3); eng1 = rs.getString(4); sci1 = rs.getString(5); } else { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid idno"); }

Comment: GUYS I HAVE EDITED MY CODING BUT IT STILL DOSENT WORK CAN SOMEONE HELP ME PLEASE??

Answer (score 0):

`rs.next` loops though the database row-wise. So you could find your matching row that way. Afterwards you can execute your `query` on this `ResultSet` and recieve the the coloumns of the row you executed your `query` on.

Comment: while(rs.next())
                {
                    if(id1 == rs.getString(1))
                    {
                        data = 1;
                    }
                }
                if(data==1)
                {
                    name1 = rs.getString(2);
                    mat1 = rs.getString(3);
                    eng1 = rs.getString(4);
                    sci1 = rs.getString(5);
                }
                else
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid idno");
                }

Comment: Try `rs.getString("name of the coloumn");`